# Error in hg convert

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension, mercurial-convert

I have a problem with hg convert. When I write in the command line "hg convert f:/test" it gives me this: abort: invalid mode ('r') or filename. What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide more details:

- Version of  Mercurial
- Source repository type

and, maybe, use full command line (destination, filemap-file, source-type)

**Add-on**

According to topic [Converting: abort: invalid mode ('r') or filename](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2012-March/042266.html) it was bug in 2.1.1, **fixed in 1-st April 2012 release**

Comment: mercurial - 2.1.1, repo type - git

Comment: @user1827283 1. Source **in your command** is not git 2. Mercurial is very outdated

Comment: now i use 2.3.2, converting is going, but stoped on "scanning source..."

Comment: This may be because in repo 18000 commits?